# is deeplinking into the google assistant app possible?

Tags: actions-on-google, deep-linking, google-home, deeplink

I want to link from my app into the Smart-Home-Control Screen of the Google Assistant App.
Unfortunately I do not find any documentation with these keywords.
Is it possible to do that?
I'm thinking off something like `googleassistant://`

If yes - how?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For conversational Actions, you can use [Action links](https://developers.google.com/assistant/engagement/action-links) to guide users to the specified intent within your Action.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about direct link to the smart home control screen but these urls will launch the home app.  You may be able to find and endpoint which shows this the control screen

https://madeby.google.com.

https://madeby.google.com/home-app.

Replace agentId with your action agent ID.

https://madeby.google.com/home-app/?deeplink=setup%2Fha_linking%3Fagent_id%3Dda-prod-agentId

See:
https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/develop/discovery